# Insert into mysql using php / html form - not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm trying to enter data into a mysql database using php / html form but it isn't working and I don't know why.  The record is not inserted and I only get a blank page after I submit the form.

Thanks,
eugenie

This is my database[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rWj9.png)

This is the html form:

```
<form method="post" action="http://thesoundclinic.co.uk/site/modules/cjaycontent/index.php?id=28">
<table class="outer" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" align="center">
<tbody>

<tr>
<td>Uid (See Main Menu) </td>
<td><input name="uid" id="uid" size="3" maxlength="10" type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="300">Full Name</td>
<td><input name="name" id="name" size="30" maxlength="30" type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="300">Location</td>
<td><input name="location" id="location" size="20" maxlength="30" type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr>

<td>Profile</td>

<td><textarea name="profile" id="profile" cols="25" rows="5">A bit about yourself... </textarea></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>Prefered Genres</td>

<td>
<table border="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" id="genres" value="Action">Action</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" id="genres" value="Adventure">Adventrue</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" id="genres" value="Horror">Horror</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" id="genres" value="Romance">Romance</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" id="genres" value="Drama">Drama</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" id="genres" value="Comedy">Comedy</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" id="genres" value="Thriller">Thriller</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" id="genres" value="Sci-fi">Sci-fi</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" id="genres" value="Crime">Crime</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" id="genres" value="Epic">Epic</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" id="genres" value="Western">Western</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" id="genres" value="Fantasy">Fantasy</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" id="genres" value="Period">Period</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" id="genres" value="Experimental">Experimental</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" id="genres" value="Documentary">Documentary</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" id="genres" value="Animation">Animation</td>
</tr>

</table></td>

</tr>

<td width="300">Describe in one word the predominant feeling of your music (e.g. epic, bizarre, melancholic, etc)</td>

<td><input name="style" id="style" size="20" maxlength="30" type="text"></td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>Areas of Interest</td>

<td><textarea name="interests" id="interests" cols="25" rows="5"> Any particular interest (animation, period, etc.). </textarea></td>

</tr>


<td>How much in GBP do you normally charge for your work?</td>

<td><textarea name="rates" id="rates" cols="25" rows="5"> Please explain... </textarea></td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>Every year we offer free sound design to up to 3 films taking part in the 48 Hour Film Challenge. Would you consider contributing your work for free? (This is a competition requirement). </td>

<td><input type="radio" name="48hfilm" id="48hfilm" value="Yes">Yes

<input type="radio" name="48hfilm" id="48hfilm" value="No">No</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td width="300" colspan="2" align="center">

<strong><br>Paste your youTube (embed) / SoundCloud (Widget) <i>iFrame</i> code in the following Fields. You can insert up to 8 codes.</strong><br>

</td>


<tr>

<td ><h3>Clip 1</h></td>

<td><input name="clip1" id="clip1" size="80" maxlength="200" type="text"></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td ><h3>Clip 2</h></td>

<td><input name="clip2" id="clip2" size="80" maxlength="200" type="text"></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td ><h3>Clip 3</h></td>

<td><input name="clip3" id="clip3" size="80" maxlength="200"

type="text"></td>

</tr>

<td ><h3>Clip 4</h></td>

<td><input name="clip4" id="clip4" size="80" maxlength="200"

type="text"></td>

</tr>

<td><h3>Clip 5</h></td>

<td><input name="clip5" id="clip5" size="80" maxlength="200"

type="text"></td>

</tr>

<td ><h3>Clip 6</h></td>

<td><input name="clip6" id="clip6" size="80" maxlength="200"

type="text"></td>

</tr>

<td ><h3>Clip 7</h></td>

<td><input name="clip7" id="clip7" size="80" maxlength="200"

type="text"></td>

</tr>

<td ><h3>Clip 8</h></td>

<td><input name="clip8" id="clip8" size="80" maxlength="200" type="text"></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td > <br>

</td>

<td> <input name="add" id="add" value="Submit" type="submit"></td>

</tr>

</tbody>

</table>

</form>
```

And this is the php code:

```
<?php

include("mainfile.php"); 
include(XOOPS_ROOT_PATH."/header.php");

$DBhost = "localhost";
$DBuser = "------";
$DBpass = "----";
$DBName = "---";
$table = "--l";
mysql_connect($DBhost,$DBuser,$DBpass) or die("Unable to connect to database");

@mysql_select_db("$DBName") or die("Unable to select database $DBName");

$sqlquery = "INSERT INTO $table
VALUES('$_POST[id]','$_POST[uid]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[location]', '$_POST[profile]',             '$_POST[genres]', '$_POST[48hfilm]', '$_POST[clip1]', '$_POST[clip2]', '$_POST[clip3]', '$_POST[clip4]',     '$_POST[clip5]', '$_POST[clip6]', '$_POST[clip7]', '$_POST[clip8]', '$_POST[rates]', '$_POST[style]', '$_POST[interests]')";



$results = mysql_query($sqlquery); 

 { 
 Print "<table class='editor'>"; 
 Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th>Name:</th> <td>$_POST[name]</td> ";
 Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th>Location:</th> <td>$_POST[location]</td> "; 
 Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th>Profile:</th> <td>$_POST[profile]</td> "; 
Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th>Genres:</th> <td>$_POST[genres]</td> "; 
Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th>48h Film Challenge?</th> <td>$_POST[48hfilm]</td> "; 
Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th>Style:</th> <td>$_POST[style]</td> "; 
Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th>Interests:</th> <td>$_POST[interests]</td> ";

 } 
 Print "</table>"; 



?>

<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="----"; // Mysql username 
$password="----"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="--c"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="---l"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

 // get value of id that sent from address bar
$uid=$_POST['uid'];

$sql = "Select * from $tbl_name WHERE uid='$uid'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

echo "<h2></h><br><p>";
echo "<div align='center'><h1>GALLERY</h><p><br></div>";
echo "<h2>Clip 1 </h><p><p>";

if($row['clip1'] != ''){ 
echo "<h2>Clip 1 </h><p><p>"; 
echo "<div align='center'>" . $row['clip1'] . "</div><p><br>"; 
} 
if($row['clip2'] != ''){ 
echo "<h2>Clip 2 </h><p><p>"; 
echo "<div align='center'>" . $row['clip2'] . "</div>"; 
} 
if($row['clip3'] != ''){ 
echo "<h2>Clip 3 </h><p><p>"; 
echo "<div align='center'>" . $row['clip3'] . "</div>"; 
} 
if($row['clip4'] != ''){ 
echo "<h2>Clip 4 </h><p><p>"; 
echo "<div align='center'>" . $row['clip4'] . "</div>"; 
}
if($row['clip5'] != ''){ 
echo "<h2>Clip 5 </h><p><p>"; 
echo "<div align='center'>" . $row['clip5'] . "</div>"; 
}
if($row['clip6'] != ''){ 
echo "<h2>Clip 6 </h><p><p>"; 
echo "<div align='center'>" . $row['clip6'] . "</div>"; 
}
if($row['clip7'] != ''){ 
echo "<h2>Clip 7 </h><p><p>"; 
echo "<div align='center'>" . $row['clip7'] . "</div>"; 
}
if($row['clip8'] != ''){ 
echo "<h2>Clip 8 </h><p><p>"; 
echo "<div align='center'>" . $row['clip8'] . "</div>"; 
}
}



?>
```

Comment: `@` is an error suppressor. Remove it from `@mysql_select_db`

Comment: I think that form field names aren't supposed to start with a number, as in `name="48hfilm"` for example.

Comment: Actually after doing a certain amount of testing, got back a parse error with `Print "<th>48h Film Challenge?</th> <td>$_POST[48hfilm]</td> ";`, so that and all other form fields starting with a number will cause errors/problems. Therefore I suggest you place a letter before all fields starting with a number. For example `$_POST[hfilm48]`

Comment: Do as I suggested above and theoretically, it should now work.

Comment: Change `<td><input type="radio" name="48hfilm" id="48hfilm" value="Yes">Yes <input type="radio" name="48hfilm" id="48hfilm" value="No">No</td>`
**to** `<td><input type="radio" name="hfilm48" id="hfilm48" value="Yes">Yes <input type="radio" name="hfilm48" id="hfilm48" value="No">No</td>` **or** `name="a_48hfilm"`

Comment: Other problem I have now is that Genres shows as "array" I thing I may have misconfigured the database. That's why I added picture. any suggestions?

Comment: @Eugenie You're welcome. So my comment worked. Mind if I put it in as an answer then? And yes could be your DB.

Comment: Yes, please do put it.   I removed the [] but still getting an array. Should I change something in the structure of the database, like change to SET or something like that?

Comment: @Eugenie I only know a little about DBs. I tend to think that you will need a `foreach` for the Genres checkbox options.

Comment: @Eugenie Try using something to the affect of `foreach($_POST['genres'] as $key => $value)` or `foreach( $_REQUEST['genres'] as $val)`

Comment: Never mind.  I'm sure I can work that one out.  Thanks a lot for your reply :)

Comment: @Eugenie You're very much welcome, cheers :) (P.s.: See my new comment above about the `foreach`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form field names aren't supposed to start with a number, as in `name="48hfilm"` for example.

After doing a certain amount of testing, I got back a parse error with `Print "<th>48h Film Challenge?</th> <td>$_POST[48hfilm]</td> ";`

Change:

```
<td><input type="radio" name="48hfilm" id="48hfilm" value="Yes">Yes 

<input type="radio" name="48hfilm" id="48hfilm" value="No">No</td>
```

To:

```
<td><input type="radio" name="hfilm48" id="hfilm48" value="Yes">Yes 

<input type="radio" name="hfilm48" id="hfilm48" value="No">No</td>
```

or start it with a letter such as `name="a_48hfilm"`